# Errors on adding multiple Google sign in buttons through google.accounts.id.renderButton

Tags: angular, google-signin

everybody.

## TLDR

I'm adding multiple Google sign-in buttons to my Angular app. Everything works, but when the component renders on the page, in the console I see a lot of errors:

```
m=credential_button_library:351 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pb')
    at Xi.j (m=credential_button_library:351:40)
```

## Long description:

I've connected the script in my index.html

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

In the social-button.component I've initialized the library (only first time, as I have a lot of social-buttons around my app) and render the button:

```
@ViewChild('googleBtn', { static: false }) googleBtn: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // init
  if (!this.isGoogleInited) {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: 'my-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      callback: (response: any) => this.handleGoogleSignIn(response),
    });

    this.isGoogleInited = true;
  }

  // render button
  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    this.googleBtn.nativeElement, // analog document.getElementById
    { size: 'large',
      type: 'standard',
      shape: 'pill',
      width: 400,
      text: 'signin_with',
      locale: 'en_US',
      logo_alignment: 'left' },
  );
}
```

As a result, I have a lot of errors in the console, when the social-button.component appears on the screen.

```
m=credential_button_library:351 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pb')
    at Xi.j (m=credential_button_library:351:40)
```

It's possible to Sign in through the Google auth popup, everything seems fine, but these vague errors are annoying.
The library is minified, and I see the source tag at the end of it, but can't understand, how to use it to get the full version

```js
//# sourceURL=/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en_US._JfGfz6KwQI.O/am=6g/d=1/rs=AF0KOtV1B61xrH6eqEBU797R2TEt4nDhkQ/m=credential_button_library
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: same issue, but with vanilla JS app. any updates?

Comment: UPD: discovered some quite hacky but working solution. Can describe in answers after testing, but only in the context of vanilla js, not angular.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @Alex Naidovich.
I got the same issue and used a bit improved Alex solution.

So, in my HTML part I have next lines:

```html
<!-- This div is hidden and used to store the real gsi button -->
<div class="gsi-button d-none"></div>
<!-- This is a user button, you can create as many buttons as you want -->
<button class="google-login">Google</button>
```

After I load GSI library I run following code:

```js
// Don't forget to add your own client_id and callback
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
    callback: YOUR_CALLBACK
});
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.querySelector('.gsi-button'), {});


const onCustomGSIButtonClick = e => {

    // Firstly, you'll have to define the real GSI button.
    // It is not actually `.g_id_signin` that GSI docs tells you to add,
    // but the child div that is created dynamically by GSI init script.
    // You can't get it by class (Google utilizes dynamic hashes for it),
    // but it's the only child that has `role` and `aria-labelledby` attributes.

    // For iOS devices google renders their button in different way
    // So we need to use a different selector
    let theRealGSIButton = 
            document
                .querySelector('[id^="gsi"][id$="-overlay"]') ?? 
            document
                .querySelector('.iframe-gsi-container')
                .querySelector('[role="button"][aria-labelledby="button-label"]') ?? 
            undefined

    // Then you define programmatic click event
    // that will be dispatched on it.

    const GSIClickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancellable: true
    });

    // Finally, you dispatch your click event on real GSI button.
    // GSI popup should appear afterwards.

    theRealGSIButton.dispatchEvent(GSIClickEvent);
}

// Listen for our event for all custom buttons
document.querySelectorAll('button.google-login').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', onCustomGSIButtonClick);
})
```

I render my button with renderButton method from JS API, but you can also use HTML API to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue at my plain js project, when tried to add the second GSI button markup. And got rid of the issue. But this answer will refer to plain JS, not Angular. If this solution will look fine for you, you will have to adapt this to Angular style by yourself. And I consider this solution to be hacky :)

The thing is you don't have to create more GSI buttons than one. Instead of this, you just create your own custom button, and attach click handler to it. That handler should programmatically dispatch `click` event on the original GSI button.

So, `click` handler for your custom button will look like this:

```
const onCustomGSIButtonClick = e => {
  
  // Firstly, you'll have to define the real GSI button.
  // It is not actually `.g_id_signin` that GSI docs tells you to add,
  // but the child div that is created dynamically by GSI init script.
  // You can't get it by class (Google utilizes dynamic hashes for it),
  // but it's the only child that has `role` and `aria-labelledby` attributes.

  const theRealGSIButton = document
    .querySelector('.g_id_signin')
    .querySelector('[role="button"][aria-labelledby="button-label"]');

  // Then you define programmatic click event 
  // that will be dispatched on it.

  const GSIClickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancellable: true
  });

  // Finally, you dispatch your click event on real GSI button.
  // GSI popup should appear afterwards.

  theRealGSIButton.dispatchEvent(GSIClickEvent);
}

// And you will want to attach this handler to your custom button.
document
  .querySelector('#your-custom-button-id')
  .addEventListener('click', onCustomGSIButtonClick);
```

Bonus benefit of this solution is that you can create your own GSI button, that is fully customizable by your own CSS.

Hope this answer will be useful.

**EDIT:** this solution fails to work on iPhone (doesn't get real button's selector), while it works fine on Android devices. Discovering further...

**EDIT 2: Do not rely on this solution.**

I failed to find a way to make this solution work on iPhone. Finally I came to this:

- before GSI script load and inserting GSI-markup: detect `window.innerWidth`;
- then load GSI script, and depending on `window.innerWidth` insert GSI-markup into desktop or mobile placeholder.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Naidovich. I had almost lost hope of getting any responses. 
All solutions like this have one weakness: if Google changes the markup, the code will break. Nevertheless, I'll try your proposal and share my feedback with you.